# Installation of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is getting stuck everytime

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 20.04

I purchased a new Asus TUF A15 (FA506IH-AL057T). It has AMD 4600H processor and Dedicated NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650. The Storage is 1TB HDD+ 256GB NVMe SSD. It comes with a Windows 10 HOME.

I tried installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and it is getting stuck always at Connect to Internet(WIFI) page. First I thought the problem is with the ISO I downloaded, So I downloaded another one.
But that also behaved the same.

I tried using a different USB Pendrive and still the same. I was using Rufus on Windows so I tried using different disk format like NTFS or FAT 32. In case of NTFS it use to get forward to net page where I have to select the Installation type(Normal Installation etc) and it get stuck there. I tired making the pendrive bootable from Startup disk creator Application in Ubuntu from another laptop which had Ubuntu installed and still the same.

I am not sure what it is I am doing wrong. I have turned OFF my Secure Boot also.

I really need to dual boot Ubuntu. Please help if I can try something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried installing Ubuntu from SAFE GRAPHICS option.

The installation was complete but was still not booting up.

Then I used recovery mode and fixed broken package then booted up Ubuntu.

As I was certain that there is a problem in graphics driver so I changed my graphics driver using Software and Update->Additional Driver pannel and selected the Nvedia graphics option.

Restarted and everything worked perfect.

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot with Try Ubuntu Without Installing
2. Get the desktop loads up
3. Connect to wifi from wifi menu on top panel
4. If it works, good. Else go to the Additional Driver and check for available drivers and select accordingly, then apply and reconnect wifi
5. Install Ubuntu from the Install Ubuntu icon

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It may be a driver problem. Try connecting to an ethernet port and troubleshooting with that connection.

You can also try not to install but to run Ubuntu without installing. Does it work? Do you have WiFi conectivity in that mode?

Is the hardware listed in the [ubuntu compatibility list](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport)? Not saying that it won't work if not, but if the hardware is listed, it might help getting support.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the same issue that I had faced when I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, a month ago. What I did is, I entered into live version by clicking 'Try Ubuntu' option. Once you enter to live version, you will see a installation widget on the desktop. Click that and it will start the installation and then it will ask for connecting the WiFi. If the WiFi does't shows up, cancel the installation and repeat the process. It worked for me the second or third time and successfully installed Ubuntu!

If this doesn't work for you, then use ethernet connection or use USB tethering from mobile.

Hope it helps you.